# .NET c# manage SQL Server Jobs

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How can I exectue a Mcrosoft SQL Server Job via console application and return a value once this job finish?

I've been reading [these docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms202348.aspx) from Microsoft, but start and stop are void methods, also as far I understand, as the name suggests, these methods are used to start and stop the jobs and they are not events that can be listened.

Are there any events to achieve this?

Comment: What values are you expecting to get back?

Comment: Jobs are executed asynchronously by the *server* and may be scheduled to run in the future. A .NET-style event mechanism doesn't make sense in this case. The easiest solution would be to poll for the job's status

Comment: @bmvr to avoid waiting for ever you should add a timeout to your code and wait only up to a point. Jobs *can* take a long time though. Nightly ETL jobs could take hours.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've to make controll jobs because some may depend on other, which means they need to run in sequence, if someone tries to trigger a job that depends on some that is running I need to know and block the execution, also this interface is a webpage, which I need to know when a certain job is finish so the user can start another one, for that reason I need to get the status of the jobs somehow in a event like style.

Comment: @bmvr that's the job of the *jobs themselves*, not your code. A job can have individual steps and call other jobs. You can get the current status and current step from the corresponding properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, It's complicate to explain I'm not the DBA, I'm just the Software Engineer, Imagine that you have  a Job(A) that loads a table, and other job(B) that consumes that information. I can't run B if A is running because the information isn't there yet, they are two independent jobs. The sql code of each dont make referente one to another.

Comment: @bmvr then you need to understand how jobs work and create a job with steps. Jobs *already* have steps that run only if the previous one finished succesfully. This isn't DBA-specific knowledge. This *is* something software engineers should know

Comment: @bmvr just install SQL Server on your machine and creat a job with a couple of steps. It's not hard

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this years ago. Actually, once jobs run SQL queries I run my queries directly using SqlCommand instead.

In that time I found that link that may help you: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/367470/Manage-SQL-Server-Agent-Jobs-using-Csharp

Comment: From that link I see there is a loop, whats worries me on using loops is to get into an infinite loop :-/

Comment: That's just one reason why link-only answers are *not* good. It's not only that the article may disappear in the future. The important points should be explained in the article itself. In this case the linked article *doesn't* explain what's going on